# Task vs Thread, сильная задержка Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Почему при работе с Task происходят такие задержки?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
  static void SomethingLong()
  {
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
      Task.Run(() => { Console.Write("="); SomethingLong(); });
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
      (new Thread(() => { Console.Write("-"); SomethingLong(); })).Start();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      Console.Write(i.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Call Thread.Sleep from the Task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20610754/2881286)

Comment: Thread.Sleep для эмуляции занятости

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что задачи используют пул потоков. Если при создании задачи в пуле не осталось потоков - то CLR выбирает создавать новый или ставит задачу в очередь.

Если заведомо известно что задача будет выполняться долго и другие не должны ее ждать - можно использовать метод `Task.Factory.StartNew` с опцией `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.